# Training simple artifical neural network to solve XOR sometimes doesn't work

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I use NN with:

- 1 input layer (2 neurons),
- 1 hidden layer (2 neurons),
- 1 output layer (1 neuron).

I train it using feed forward and backpropagation algorithm. I also initialize weights randomly from range `[-1, 1]` (also tried `[0, 1]`, but it doesn't change anything actually). And often (like 4/5 times) everything is trained properly (for inputs

`[00, 01, 10, 11]`

it outputs

`[~0.1, ~0.9, ~0.9, ~0.1]`

, respectively), but the remaining 1/5 times it outputs like

`[~0.5, ~0.6, ~0.4, ~0.1]`

(by `~number` I mean a value around the `number` e.g. `~0.1` may be either `0.098` or `0.132` or similiar)

It doesn't matter if I train it for, let's say, 20 seconds or 10 minutes, it's still the same.
I'm pretty sure it's because of the randomly intialized weights, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

How shall I initialize the weights for this problem as well as for others (if it causes the problem)?
How do you do that? Have you any idea what causes this problem or you need some code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, organize your question in a way that is more readable.

Comment: I think I did it properly. Thanks for describing the problem instead of just minusing my post, as you noticed - I'm new. Let me know if there's something more to organize.

Comment: It looks much better now. That way people will answer faster. Good luck!

Comment: How is your training data organized? Do you randomize the order? If you're concerned it's the random weights, try initializing them manually, or with a seed so that you get deterministic results

Comment: Yes, I randomize the order. Obviously, I could initialize the weights manually, but for one problem they could be fine, but for other one not and I'd have to find new initializing wieghts. I'm rather looking for a more general and automatic way to create nn. As I mentioned, my training doesn't work all the time, thus I'd like to know the reason of that. Have you ever had similiar problem?

Comment: I'm not an expert on NN's. But I can imagine since there being so few neurons and weights that if the distribution of the weights every now and then becomes skewed, it could affect things negatively. But it wouldn't be in the same way every time. That's why I think it's a good idea if you can 'lock' things down by having them be deterministic. If you still experience problems, you know where to look. The reason I asked about the data is that the NN could unlearn things if the order of the data allows for it. Have you tried increasing the training data set?